# How to use graphviz to draw nodes and edges using c# in windows application

Tags: c#, graph, nodes, graphviz, edges

I am developing a windows application using c# in visual studio 2012.I want to draw nodes and edges using graphviz.
The no. of edges and nodes to be drawn are stored in a table in the database.Please suggest how to do this right from importing the library and using it in the application.GRAPHVIZ guide wasn't of much help to me. Is there any other tool apart from Graphviz which is easy to understand and use with visual studio.

Answer (score 0):

I tried http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18870/Dot-WPF-a-WPF-control-for-viewing-Dot-graphs and it worked really fine for me.